# $\underset{y}{\text{maximize}} \; K \int_{y}^{\infty} f^{2}(x) dx - \int_{y}^{\infty} g^{2}(x) dx$

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization, numerical-optimization, non-convex-optimization

I want to know what I can say about the following problem:

$$\underset{y}{\text{maximize}} \; K  \int_{y}^{\infty} f^{2}(x) dx - \int_{y}^{\infty} g^{2}(x) dx $$

where $K \in \mathbb{R}_{+}$, $y \geq 0$, and $f,g \in \mathbb{R}$, and $f^{2}(x)$ $g^{2}(x)$ are decreasing functions.

It is clear that $\int_{y}^{\infty} f^{2}(x) dx$ and $\int_{y}^{\infty} g^{2}(x) dx$ are decreasing functions of $y$.

Questions:

- Can I solve this problem by simply finding:

$$ \frac{d}{d y} \left( K  \int_{y}^{\infty} f^{2}(x) dx - \int_{y}^{\infty} g^{2}(x) dx \right) = 0  $$

** Or do I need other restrictions on these functions?

---

If I do this, knowing the decreasing nature of these functions (ie $ \underset{x \rightarrow \infty}{\text{lim}} \; f^{2}(x) = g^{2}(x) = 0)$ I get:

$$  g^{2}(y) - K f^{2}(y)= 0 $$

Then, I could find the result numerically -- assuming I know the functional forms of $f,g$.

Is this approach reasonable? Will it solve the original problem?

---

Thanks!

Comment: Yes this is perfectly reasonable assuming there exists a root to this equation, then it would be a turning point. It is not necessarily true that a root exists but do have a go.

Comment: @GeorgeDewhirst This is what I was questioning actually. So after this turning point, it would mean that my objective function starts decreasing? And before that, it doesn't? For some reason today, this is difficult to wrap my puny mind around haha

Comment: it would be a local maximum which may well be a global maximum too. It increases up to this point and decreases after (as you'd expect)

Comment: You can basically rule out a maximum at $y=\infty$ as this makes the objective zero, thus any local maximum would also be global

Comment: @GeorgeDewhirst Ah, okay. If I could show convexity then I would understand. Thank you.

Comment: let me know what you get as your numerical solutions to the equation